# Get Wordpress Category outside the loop

Tags: wordpress, embed, categories

I need Javacript that will simply return the category of the current post in which my slider plugin in embedded.  Anyone know what this is?

Comment: a javascript? please provide more details about what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using js as javascript is not server side language , So if you want to get the category of the current post and pass it to js , It is possible

First get the category of the current post :

```
global $post;
$postcat = get_the_category( $post->ID );
```

Then just get the category name by the following string :
`$cat_name = get_cat_name( $postcat );`

Then if you want to use the $cat_name in js you can use `$cat_name` and also you can test it using alert js method as example.

```
alert('<?php echo $cat_name; ?>');
```

Comment: Thansk for your response.  What I'm actually trying to do is simple.  I want to pass the name of the current category to the callback code on my embedded slider to tell it which slide to open.  I don't know how I'd use your code for that.  Here's the callback: function(event){
  var api = event.target;
  api.gotoSlide(3)
}

Comment: So for instance, if the category is "myCategory" I want to got to slide 3.

Comment: if (3) is the category id then all you got to do is 

function(event){ var api = event.target; api.gotoSlide(<?php echo $postcat; ?>) }